# Behaviour of the Elvis Operator ?: In Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

[image: Why is res1 and res2 different?]

Why is res1 and res2 different? Only difference is the presence of an enclosing bracket.

Comment: Obviously `?:` has higher priority than `==`.

Comment: BTW, the title is wrong.  Kotlin's null-coalescing (elvis) operator is a binary operator (with 2 arguments); Kotlin doesn't _have_ any ternary (3-argument) operators.  (It doesn't need one like Java's, as its `if` construct is an expression, so takes on that role.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val res1 = bool ?: a == b
```

is the same as

```
val res1 = (bool ?: a) == b
```

`bool` is not `null` (it is `true`)  so (bool ?: a) returns `true` and `true == b` is `false`, the result stored in res1.

This is because `?:` is binding the left side to the first possible parameter on the right side of it, which is only `a` and not `a == b` what you are expecting.

You can look this up at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions 
if Equality (`==`) would have had a higher precedence than Elvis(`?:`) it would be your expected result.